# Native Wordpress Video Shortcode Not Working After Post is Loaded via Ajax

Tags: ajax, video-player

I'm loading post content into a modal via ajax. Some of the post have video that is added via the wordpress native video shortcode. The video shows up in the post, but none of the mediaElement.js mark-up is being added, so the video is no longer responsive.

If the video is loaded on the page, and not via AJAX everything is working fine.

I can see that wp-mediaelement.js is loading on the page, and I have also added `$('video,audio').mediaelementplayer();` to the AJAX success function, but I get the error "mediaelementplayer is not a function".

When the modal is visible I've tried adding `$('video,audio').mediaelementplayer();` directly to the console and I get the same error.

[This is the post](https://designorbital.com/tutorials/how-to-use-ajax-in-wordpress/) I used to build the AJAX call, so my code is structured the same way, if that helps in troubleshooting.

Comment: Try passing `window.wp.mediaelement.initialize` as ajax success callback or just call it directly inside your existing callback `window.wp.mediaelement.initialize();` if other stuff need to be run.

Comment: Please don't link to someone elses code, show your own code when you have a question about it.